# Determine python version in Easy Install

Tags: python, python-2.7, easy-install, centos5, python-2.4

I wan't to install 'twisted' module on CentOS 5.9 . There is python 2.4 by default on it and because of other program dependencies I can't remove python 2.4 .
I have installed Python 2.7 by `yum install python27` and installed Easy Install by `yum install python-setuptools` . Now when I try to install 'twisted' with `easy_install twisted` I got this error:

```
<  ... truncated ... >
Running Twisted-12.3.0/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-YeUGBS/Twisted-12.3.0/egg-dist-tmp-NhwZo-
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/easy_install", line 7, in ?
    sys.exit(
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1670, in main
    with_ei_usage(lambda:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1659, in with_ei_usage
    return f()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1674, in <lambda>
    distclass=DistributionWithoutHelpCommands, **kw
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/distutils/core.py", line 149, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/distutils/dist.py", line 946, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/distutils/dist.py", line 966, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 211, in run
    self.easy_install(spec, not self.no_deps)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 446, in easy_install
    return self.install_item(spec, dist.location, tmpdir, deps)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 471, in install_item
    dists = self.install_eggs(spec, download, tmpdir)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 655, in install_eggs
    return self.build_and_install(setup_script, setup_base)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 930, in build_and_install
    self.run_setup(setup_script, setup_base, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 919, in run_setup
    run_setup(setup_script, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 26, in run_setup
    DirectorySandbox(setup_dir).run(
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 63, in run
    return func()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 29, in <lambda>
    {'__file__':setup_script, '__name__':'__main__'}
  File "setup.py", line 64, in ?
  File "setup.py", line 46, in main
  File "./twisted/__init__.py", line 47
    class Dummy(object):
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

As you see, Easy Install use python 2.4 instead of python 2.7 . How can it force it to use python 2.7 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can manually use which ever Python version you want by typing e.g. `Python2.7 <script>`. Try to execute `python2.7 -m easy_install twisted` instead.

If for some reason `easy_install` wasn't installed for `Python 2.7` you can download and install it manually [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools).

Comment: I think you need a `-m` before easy_install there.